# How to check what endpoints Java app is requesting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

There's a mobile app I need to debug and find out what endpoints with what parameters is it using. How can I do it?

I thought about using Wireshark, but all endpoints are in https. I tried using Android Studia (I am not Java developer, so I have no experience using it) but the app from official source did not start.

I tried to analyze the code and I think I found right endpoints, but I can't find format of parameters that are supposed to be sent with those requests.
Is there any other way of finding out other than debugging those .smali files?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: I don't have access to anything but application. It's McDonalds app, I was looking for direct api endpoints in the internet but nothing found.

Comment: Are these APIs public? If so there is 100% a api documentation

Comment: I'm not sure of definition of "public" API, because anybody can connect with that but it's meant only for public app and there's no public documentation. I've been looking for this.